# How to read the MCC code from the PoS-terminal using APDU commands

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I'm trying to implement the HostApduService on Android phone and I need to read the MCC code from the PoS-terminal

I'm sendring on the terminal's SELECT AID the response with the next tags:
TTQ - 9F6604
Amount - 9F0206
Amount2 - 9F0306
Country code - 9F1A02
TVR - 9505
Currency - 5F2A02
Date - 9A03
Transaction Type - 9C01
MCC - 9F1502
Random number - 9F3704

RAW request
6F348407A0000000031010A5299F381B9F66049F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F15029F3704BF0C089F5A0560084006439000

RAW response
80A8000025832334A04000000000004677000000000000080400000000000980191003000000E0AFD09500

As you can see, terminal sending the MCC as 0000 and it's wrong

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

If a data element requested in PDOL is not present in the terminal, the terminal will send hexadecimal zeros in place of the requested data in the expected length.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand how the terminal works without configured MCC code.

Comment: unless you have a very specific requirement( can you explain ), I don't think you need to maintain MCC at the terminal. In most cases it is sufficient the acquirer has the info.

Answer (score 0):

Merchant Category Code (MCC) is managed by `Terminal`, check with your terminal vendor to configure MCC. it can be offline tool update, or OTA config update.

Comment: I tried on the few separate terminals, which works in the cafe, cinema, and store. And no one answers me on the MCC request. I feel that I do something with the mistake. In any case thanks for the answer

Comment: @Vitaliy they (the merchant) won't know, the POS was already setup and they only know how to use it. what i mentioned is `terminal vendor`, not the `merchant`.